# How do I filter based on if two column values "straddle" any of the values in another table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

An example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

Table A

| Index | FirstValue | SecondValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 340 | 700 |
| 2 | 20 | 250 |
| 3 | 60 | 150 |
| 4 | 180 | 540 |
| 5 | 590 | 1000 |

Table B

| StraddleValue |
| --- |
| 190 |
| 830 |
| 300 |

Desired output:

| Index | FirstValue | SecondValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 340 | 700 |
| 3 | 60 | 150 |

I want to filter out any rows where, for any StraddleValue, FirstValue < StraddleValue AND SecondValue > StraddleValue.
I'm not sure how to do this without hardcoding the StraddleValues..which obviously isn't scalable.

Thanks.

Comment: confusing.  which stradleValue do you want the results for? why desired row 3? which one makes that a result?

Comment: If ANY of the StraddleValues fall in between the FirstValue and SecondValue, I want to exclude that row from my result. Row 3 is desired because non of the StraddleValues fall in between 60 and 150.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where a.FirstValue < b.StraddleValue and
                        a.SecondValue > b.StraddleValue
                 );
```